# Are the questions about knowledge/information about things described in English appropriate?

Tags: discussion, appropriate-questions, on-topic-off-topic

I would like to ask about the dress code: **royal touch**. I would like to know how a man should be dressed if he would like to follow the code.

From one point of view, it is definitely an **off-topic** since it is not a question about grammar or language usage.

On the other hand it can be considered as a question about a **definition(explanation) of an English word/phrase** which should be suitable for EL&U. What is more, I believe that people here can know about this matter more then on the other sites.

So are the questions in this sense appropriate in EL&U? If no, where should I ask about this particular issue?

Comment: Definitely Off-Topic. We hold ourselves out as experts in use of the English language, not in dress or etiquette. You may ask "How am I to understand X?" or "How am I to say or write X?", but you may not ask "How am I to dress in accordance with X?" or "Does such and such garment conform to X?"

Comment: @StoneyB: Couldn't agree more. This one was [asked and closed elsewhere on SO](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6201/) (there's probably no such dress code anyway).

Comment: @ Yeah I asked that :) I did not get any answer if the question is appropriate here, so I asked somewhere else: ) And yes there is no such a code. I found it out few days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is about the meaning of a word/phrase, it is on-topic. If the question requires to know how a man should be dressed if he follows that dress code, it is off-topic.

In the first case, frame the question to evidence for which phrase you want to know the meaning; provide a context to the phrase, and make the question clear also to who doesn't know anything about that dress code.

Comment: Understood. My question would be off-topic than. Thank you for the clarification.